# A spike in CPU utilization when opening a path which has numerous large files whilst running AVAST antivirus

Tags: windows-7, avast

I have AVAST installed on Windows 7 and whenever I open a path e.g. D:{Directory}* which has substantial large files i.e. in excess of 200GB, CPU utilization jumps to 100% and it appears as though as Windows is attempting to list the files i.e. the green scrollbar is running across Windows Explorer (be keen to know the proper term).

I initially thought it may have been something to do with the search indexer however having looked at Task Manager, it was the AVAST service hogging all of the CPU. The only way I can prevent this is to disable AVAST which I don't or to stop a specific service within AVAST i.e. File Shield which monitors reads and writes continuously.

This did not use to occur in the past however seems more frequent now. I have run a scan on the host and no viruses have been detected nor malware. The host has approximately 4GB RAM.

Comment: Are you hearing the HDD spin up as if it was asleep?

Comment: When was the last time that you updated Avast?

Comment: @Raystafarian - Nope

Comment: @EBGreen - It is updated daily as it is set to automatic updates.

Comment: Is that definition updates daily or updates to the actual software? I don't use Avast so I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @EBGreen - Both. So if there is an update to the application, it updates it automatically however it appears the daily updates are limited to signatures.

Comment: So my first guess would to be to research what software updates were done around the time that the problem started.

Comment: @EBGreen - Not sure which update may have caused such an issue but how would start the research?

Comment: I would start with the Avast site. Check to see if they have revision history/description. There may also be a revision log on your machine. If they have a forum, see if anyone else has a similar problem. Especially from around the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avast is scanning the files, especially if they are archives. Avast has an exceptions list, try adding the top-level folder to this exception list and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: Thanks. I figured so much but I don't want it to exclude the directory as files are being copied across all the time and they need to be scanned as those files are then backed up.